# Express-brute not working in my routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

I have a question with the module express-brute I can't reach a simple implementation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-brute).

I actually place the protection in a part of my routes but it seems to be not working. I made a request more than 20 times in less than a minute but it did not block anything or block the ip. Any idea how this should be working?

**security.js**

```
     require('connect-flash');


        module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
          var ExpressBrute = require('express-brute'),
        moment = require('moment'),
        store;

      store = new ExpressBrute.MemoryStore();
      var failCallback = function(req, res, next, nextValidRequestDate) {
        req.flash('error', "You've made too many failed attempts in a short period of time, please try again " + moment(nextValidRequestDate).fromNow());
      // res.redirect('/login'); // brute force protection triggered, send them back to the login page 
      };
      var handleStoreError = function(error) {
        log.error(error); // log this error so we can figure out what went wrong 
        // cause node to exit, hopefully restarting the process fixes the problem 
        throw {
          message: error.message,
          parent: error.parent
        };
      }
      // No more than 1000 login attempts per day per IP 
      var globalBruteforce = new ExpressBrute(store, {
        freeRetries: 20,
        attachResetToRequest: false,
        refreshTimeoutOnRequest: false,
        minWait: 25 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 day 1 hour (should never reach this wait time) 
        maxWait: 25 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 day 1 hour (should never reach this wait time) 
        lifetime: 24 * 60 * 60, // 1 day (seconds not milliseconds) 
        failCallback: failCallback,
        handleStoreError: handleStoreError
      });

      return globalBruteforce;

    }
```

**app.js**

```
var secure = require('./middleware/security');
var app = express();
var globalBruteforce = new secure();

app.use('/api', auth, globalBruteforce.prevent);
//more routes
```

Call made 20 times:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/user/systems
```

I actually place the code in the systems route but seems not to be working, any sucesfull code of express-brute in local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only works on directly hosted sites not in localhost as I can see..